# How to securely pass time based credentials to google cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm searching for an efficient way to store credentials inside google cloud functions that are only valid for 30 days.

My current approach is to set the username and password with `firebase functions:config:set service.username="username" service.password="password"` and sign the service in and write the response with credentials to the `os.tmpdir()/creds.json`.

The problem with this approach is that the `os.tmpdir()/creds.json` is deleted every x seconds (maybe due to cold starts). Is there a more efficient approach then just signing in the service every time or making a additional request to the cloud firestore to retrieve/store the credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions server instances are short-lived, as you have observed.  I wouldn't store anything in those instances, other than what you might use temporarily as an optimization.

Instead, you will need to use some persistent storage, such as a database or Cloud Storage.  You don't have to make a request to it every time, just as often as a new server instance is allocated to handle load.